# Using external library in PySpark UDF pickle error

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pickle

I'm trying the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("udf").getOrCreate()

def gender(s):
    m = MorphAnalyzer()
    return m.parse(s)[0].tag.gender

gen = F.udf(gender, T.StringType())

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"name": ["кирилл", "вавила"]}))

df.select(gen("name").alias("gender")).show()
```

and more or less expectedly getting the following error message:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 29.0 (TID 151)
net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.cloudpickle.cloudpickle._make_skeleton_class). This happens when an unsupported/unregistered class is being unpickled that requires construction arguments. Fix it by registering a custom IObjectConstructor for this class.
    at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:759)
    at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:199)
```

What could be the easiest way to circumvent the error (if any) ?

Comment: The easiest way to circumvent this error is to register a custom IObjectConstructor for the class that is causing the error.

Comment: @JDong Would you please show the line of code I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`pandas_udf`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) which is vectorized (more efficient compared to a regular `udf`).

```py
import pandas as pd
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types as T, functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("udf").getOrCreate()

@F.pandas_udf(T.StringType())
def gender(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(lambda x: MorphAnalyzer().parse(x)[0].tag.gender)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({"name": ["кирилл", "вавила", "софия"]}))
df.withColumn("gender", gender("name")).show()
# +------+------+
# |  name|gender|
# +------+------+
# |кирилл|  masc|
# |вавила|  masc|
# | софия|  femn|
# +------+------+
```

In some systems, you may not need `pyspark.sql.types` library solely for `pandas_udf`, the function could be defined like this:

```py
@F.pandas_udf('string')
def gender(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(lambda x: MorphAnalyzer().parse(x)[0].tag.gender)
```

**Update:** You could also use `Iterator` class in order to create `MorphAnalyzer` object once for every batch.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, types as T, functions as F
from typing import Iterator

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("udf").getOrCreate()

@F.pandas_udf(T.StringType())
def gender(s: Iterator[pd.Series]) -> Iterator[pd.Series]:
    m = MorphAnalyzer()
    for e in s:
        yield e.apply(lambda x: m.parse(x)[0].tag.gender)
```

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - Thanks for the feedback. Please take a look at the updated version. I have added the `Iterator` which could make the performance better.

Comment: Using [`RDD.mapPartitions()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.mapPartitions.html) would probably be even more efficient and won't require any pandas.

Answer (score 1):

The error means Spark can't pickle(serialize) the object you passed. The class of that object is a custom type(`TypedGrammeme`) defined by Pymorphy2.
So, convert to a `str` like the following.

```
def gender(s):
    ...
    return str(m.parse(s)[0].tag.gender)
```

Also, you should avoid to do a resource intensive task in your UDF, such as creating a `MorphAnalyzer`. Create a single instance and reuse it using a global variable.